# Jquery Web Browser?

Tags: jquery, browser, joomla, touch, kiosk

At the moment, I'm developing a web application in Joomla for a touchscreen kiosk that will be split into two screens. On the left side, there will be a menu, and the contents will be on the right side.

One of the requisites is that the application has its "own web browser" (if a user wants to navigate online he can do it inside the app) that opens only on the right side screen.

What kind of solution do you recommend? jquery? other software?

Please remember that it is a touchscreen (keypad, etc, lol).  Also, the OS is windows 7.

Comment: How about an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Iframe is pretty much the only option aside from flash, but with iFrames you won't have control of it once it leaves your domain.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an `<iframe>`.  Just be careful, as iframes can be broken out of.  The best thing to do is to write an actual native kiosk application that can add limitations on this sort of behavior.  There is no way to add such restrictions with a standard browser and JavaScript only.

Comment: You will be able to limit the security issues with a browser plugin as well, and it's easier to code than a full-featured application.